# Cannot open source file "llvm/IR/Attributes.inc" message when building LLVM?

Tags: build, clang, visual-studio-2019, llvm

I get this message when I try to build LLVM using Visual Studio 2019. Has someone encountered similar problem?
[image]
Also, I'm getting this error that "Project file does not exist." and something about CustomBuild.[image]

I get the same error with others .inc files

Comment: What CMake version are you using?

Comment: @arrowd Version 3.16.5